# Are there any naming conventions to follow while working with boilerplate code import and export?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
export default class SampleClass extends Component {
}
```

while importing this class which of the following is correct?

```
import sampleClass(same as class name) from '.module1';  or

import Myclass(Some custome name) from '.module1';
```

Comment: That's entirely up to you. You'll probably find as many opinions on this as there are people who see this question. I prefer using the class name because it makes jumping to that file in my editor easier but there are no right or wrong way about it.

Comment: Thank you @ivarni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component:-
app.js

```
export default class App extends Component{
    //

  }
```

While importing components You should always import as it is:-

```
import App from "./components/app";
```

Since you have added redux as a tag so I might guess you arisen this question while working with reducers, if i am not wrong(really sorry if i am wrong).In case of reducers they always return some object (state) a reducer always look like this

**reducer-post.js**

```
export default function(){
    //return [] 

}
```

So while importing reducers you can use any name just like this

```
import AnyReducer from "./reducers/reducer-post"
```

Since reducers are functions here so by default they are imported from it, but in the case of components, they were the class so we need to explicitly import them by name.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same name is unnecessary for default exports, but becomes necessary in case of [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

So it's better to always use the name defined in export.

Comment: @Mikhali--So, I don't use the same name incase of named exports, will it throw any error?

Comment: It should throw something like `export 'notExisting' was not found in 'module-name'`. But you can use alias if needed: `import { member as alias } from "module-name";`